# Can I inline these sequence of stream operators?

Tags: java, java-stream

I've got the following code:

```
public List<PolygonStat> groupItemsByTypeAndWeight(List<Item> items)
    {
        Map<Type, List<Item>> typeToItem = items
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(
                                item -> item.type,
                                Collectors.toList()
                        )
                );
        // For some reason we want to make a distinction between weighted items within type
        ArrayList<WeightedItem> weightedItems = new ArrayList<>();
        typeToItem.forEach(
                // List to list function
                (type, items) -> weightedItems.addAll(createWeightedList(type, items))
        );
        return weightedItems;
    }
```

I don't really like how I create `ArrayList<WeightedItem> weightedItems = new ArrayList<>();` here. Is there an opportunity to reduce it to one `return` operator (i.e.: `return items.stream().(...).toList()`. I thought about using a `flatMap` but `forEach` for `.entrySet` should return `void`.

Comment: So why are you using a foreach instead of stream, flatmap, collect?

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.type, Collectors.toList())` can be simplified to `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.type))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, instead of saving the intermediate result into a map, just create a new stream from its entrySet. And then by using the `map()` operation, you can map each entry to the new `WeightedItem`.

```
public List<PolygonStat> groupItemsByTypeAndWeight(List<Item> items){
    return items.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.type))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(entry -> createdWeightedList(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Haha... I clicked and navigated away... Just seeing that we came up with identical solutions... (except that yours formatted better...)

Comment: @ErnestKiwele oh well, yours was probably the answer that should have stayed though

Comment: That doesn't matter, there was only one answer anyway

Comment: @ErnestKiwele you don't need to delete your answer. this happens a lot :)